# Plotting a function by randomly choosing the values of two parameters

Tags: plotting

Given the function:

```
 fun[a_, b_, x_] = 
  Sqrt[1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[a]] + Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[b]] + Sqrt[
   1 + x^2 + 2 x Cos[a + b]];
```

I want to Plot it with respect to $x$, by choosing randomly the values of $a$ and $b$ (need not be same) from the interval $[0,2\pi]$. I expect a two dimensional plot with "lots of dots", each dot corresponding to a value of the given function corresponding to $x$ for some value of  parameters $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fun[a_, b_, x_] = Sqrt[1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[a]] +
   Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[b]] + Sqrt[1 + x^2 + 2 x Cos[a + b]];

xmax = 2;

{fmin, fmax} = (#[{fun[a, b, x], 0 <= a <= 2 Pi,
      0 <= b <= 2 Pi, -xmax <= x <= xmax}, {a, b, 
      x}] & /@
   {NMinValue, NMaxValue})

(* {2., 8.} *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[fun[a, b, x], {x, -xmax, xmax},
  PlotRange -> {fmin, fmax},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, fun})],
 {{a, 3}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 3}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[fun[a2, b2, x],
  {x, -xmax, xmax}, {a2, 0, 2 Pi},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "a"}),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{b2, 3, "b"}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[fun[a3, b3, x],
  {x, -xmax, xmax}, {b3, 0, 2 Pi},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "b"}),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{a3, 3, "a"}, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot3D[fun[a4, b4, x],
 {x, -xmax, xmax}, {a4, 0, 2 Pi}, {b4, 0, 2 Pi},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "a", "b"}),
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right you want to plot `{x,fun[a,b,x]}`?

Try

```
fun[a_, b_, x_] :=Sqrt[1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[a]] + Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[b]] +Sqrt[1 + x^2 + 2 x Cos[a + b]];

Plot[Evaluate@
Table[fun[RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], x], {i, 1,50}], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic} ,AxesLabel -> {"x", "fun[x]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can one show the same using density plot? I think that would make more sense here.